# How to print same row data in multiple time from pdb file in perl

Tags: perl, bioinformatics

I am new in perl, I ma trying to write a program to input pdb file (from Directory, I have 3000 files) and output will save another directory (Another folder).

Code:

```
open( filehandler, "Document1.txt" ) or die $!;    #Input file
my @file1     = <filehandler>;
my $OutputDir = 'C:\test_result_file';

foreach my $line (@file1) {
    chomp $line;
    open( fh, "$line" ) or die $!;
    open( out, ">$OutputDir/$line.pdb" ) or die $!;

    while ( $file = <fh> ) {
        if ( $file =~ /^ATOM.{9}(?:CG|CD1|CD2B|CE1|CE2|CZ|C|O|CB|CG|CD)/ ) {
            $hash{$1}{$2}++;
        }
        foreach $key ( sort { $hash{$1} <=> $hash{$2} or $1 cmp $2 } keys %hash ) {
            print out $key;
        }
    }
    print "Completed", "\n";
}
```

for example input file:

```
ATOM   1752  CG  TYR A 248      89.088  39.843  51.944  1.00 32.03           C  
ATOM   1753  CD1 TYR A 248      89.759  39.356  50.810  1.00 37.15           C  
ATOM   1754  CD2 TYR A 248      87.727  40.049  51.864  1.00 32.81           C  
ATOM   1755  CE1 TYR A 248      89.078  39.081  49.646  1.00 36.00           C  
ATOM   1756  CE2 TYR A 248      87.035  39.774  50.706  1.00 35.66           C  
ATOM   1757  CZ  TYR A 248      87.708  39.285  49.599  1.00 35.16           C  
ATOM   7394  C   GLN B 331      37.664  74.934  36.854  1.00 22.75           C  
ATOM   7395  O   GLN B 331      37.728  73.730  36.607  1.00 31.73           O  
ATOM   7396  CB  GLN B 331      37.467  76.222  34.712  1.00 27.88           C  
ATOM   7397  CG  GLN B 331      36.515  76.825  33.693  1.00 32.42           C  
ATOM   7398  CD  GLN B 331      35.390  75.877  33.328  1.00 35.70           C
```

Expected output:
A chain:

```
ATOM   1753  CD1 TYR A 248      89.759  39.356  50.810  1.00 37.15            C  
ATOM   1752  CG  TYR A 248      89.088  39.843  51.944  1.00 32.03           C  
ATOM   1754  CD2 TYR A 248      87.727  40.049  51.864  1.00 32.81           C  
ATOM   1755  CE1 TYR A 248      89.078  39.081  49.646  1.00 36.00           C

ATOM   1753  CD1 TYR A 248      89.759  39.356  50.810  1.00 37.15           C  
ATOM   1754  CD2 TYR A 248      87.727  40.049  51.864  1.00 32.81           C  
ATOM   1755  CE1 TYR A 248      89.078  39.081  49.646  1.00 36.00           C 
ATOM   1756  CE2 TYR A 248      87.035  39.774  50.706  1.00 35.66           C  

ATOM   1754  CD2 TYR A 248      87.727  40.049  51.864  1.00 32.81           C  
ATOM   1755  CE1 TYR A 248      89.078  39.081  49.646  1.00 36.00           C 
ATOM   1756  CE2 TYR A 248      87.035  39.774  50.706  1.00 35.66           C  
ATOM   1757  CZ  TYR A 248      87.708  39.285  49.599  1.00 35.16           C
```

B chain:

```
ATOM   7394  C   GLN B 331      37.664  74.934  36.854  1.00 22.75           C  
ATOM   7395  O   GLN B 331      37.728  73.730  36.607  1.00 31.73           O  
ATOM   7396  CB  GLN B 331      37.467  76.222  34.712  1.00 27.88           C  
ATOM   7397  CG  GLN B 331      36.515  76.825  33.693  1.00 32.42           C 

ATOM   7395  O   GLN B 331      37.728  73.730  36.607  1.00 31.73           O  
ATOM   7396  CB  GLN B 331      37.467  76.222  34.712  1.00 27.88           C  
ATOM   7397  CG  GLN B 331      36.515  76.825  33.693  1.00 32.42           C  
ATOM   7398  CD  GLN B 331      35.390  75.877  33.328  1.00 35.70           C  

ATOM   7396  CB  GLN B 331      37.467  76.222  34.712  1.00 27.88           C  
ATOM   7397  CG  GLN B 331      36.515  76.825  33.693  1.00 32.42           C  
ATOM   7398  CD  GLN B 331      35.390  75.877  33.328  1.00 35.70           C  
ATOM   7394  C   GLN B 331      37.664  74.934  36.854  1.00 22.75           C
```

Chain ID may be a to h. so, rule is see above expected output: First four row will unique and then line five will be same row of second row and will add new row as eight line row.

I am unable to write a code to solve this problem, any one pl help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You have good example data, expected output and an [mcve]. But you have not asked a question. Please [edit] and tell us what you are struggling with.

Comment: What do you expect `$2` to hold, if you are only capturing one match in your regular expression?

Comment: Also, I suspect where you write `$1` and `$2` in your `sort` line, you actually mean `$a` and `$b` which are the special sort variables.

Comment: I just reformatted your code a bit. I hope you don't mind. If so, feel free to revert my edit.

Comment: @Perl Dog, Thanks dear, But I am not getting any output? all output file is blank?

Comment: In your `sort` line you have to use `$a` and `$b` instead of `$1` and `$2`, like @xxfelixxx [suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39929308/how-to-print-same-row-data-in-multiple-time-from-pdb-file-in-perl?noredirect=1#comment67144005_39929308). See [sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I have to say your code is rather confusing but what I get from the data samples and further explanation is:

- There should be a window of four lines moving through the input lines.
- The window contents (all four lines) should be printed as you advance to each new line.
- The window should be reset each time a new sequence is encountered.
- Each line is a series of space delimited fields and the fifth field identifies the sequence.

The window contents can be stored in a simple Perl array (see `@window` in the snippet below). You simply append data to it with [`push`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html) and remove the first line with [`shift`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html) as you move to a next line. When the sequence changes, print the current window and reset it. In the sample code below I made an assumption that sequences do not intermix. If this is note the case, you need to read all the input beforehand and sort it as necessary.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $win_len = 4;
my @window = ();
my $prev_chain = "";

while (<>) {
    my ($atom_name, $chain) = (split)[2, 4];
    next unless $atom_name =~ /\b(?:CG|CD1|CD2B|CE1|CE2|CZ|C|O|CB|CG|CD)\b/;
    if ($chain eq $prev_chain) {
        if (@window == $win_len) {
            print_window();
            shift @window;
        }
        push @window, $_;
    } else {
        print_window() if @window;
        @window = ($_);
        $prev_chain = $chain;
    }
}
print_window() if @window;

sub print_window {
    print foreach @window;
    print "\n";
}
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/oOB8bF

The script reads data from STDIN and prints result to STDOUT for the sake of simplicity. Your code sample suggests you store a list of files to process in the `Document1.txt` and the actual input is read from these files. In this case you need an extra loop:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $OutputDir = 'C:/test_result_file';
open my $dir, "Document1.txt" or die "Failed to open Document1.txt:$!";
chomp(my @files = <$dir>);

foreach my $file (@files) {
    my $win_len = 4;
    my @window = ();
    my $prev_chain = "";

    open my $input, $file or die "failed to open $file: $!\n";
    open my $output, '>', "$OutputDir/$file.pdb" or die "failed to open $OutputDir/$file.pdb: $!\n";
    while (<$input>) {
        my ($atom_name, $chain) = (split)[2, 4];
        next unless $atom_name =~ /\b(?:CG|CD1|CD2B|CE1|CE2|CZ|C|O|CB|CG|CD)\b/;
        if ($chain eq $prev_chain) {
            if (@window == $win_len) {
                print_window($output, @window);
                shift @window;
            }
            push @window, $_;
        } else {
            print_window($output, @window) if @window;
            @window = ($_);
            $prev_chain = $chain;
        }
    }
    print_window($output, @window) if @window;
}

sub print_window {
    my $fh = shift;
    print $fh $_ foreach @_;
    print $fh "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, If I need to specify the ATOM Name by my sequence, like: -CE2-CD1-CE1-CD2. I don't want all of atom then?

Comment: Then you just need to skip the iteration if unless the third field matches the ATOM name criteria. I've updated the answer with the regex provided in your question's example. Please note the word boundary anchor (`\b`) -- it filters out names like `CG10` or `ACDC`.

Comment: Thanks dear, If I need  CE1|CG|CB|CD1 in same sequence. first CE1 row and then CG row, then CB row and then CD1 row. I need to follow sequence. I need random atom and then want to follow one sequence.

Comment: One more help, How to select random atom name ? In previous program i am getting some output null, because some of input file is like that: HETATM15056  O4B NAD A 500      14.003  14.203   8.927  1.00 17.39           O , I want to HETATM Data as well separate.

Comment: The question is getting diverse as the new requirements emerge. Let's clarify these requirements. First, the initial ones are listed in the four bullet points at the beginning of my answer (let's call them R1-R4). Second, we only need consider lines with the third field matching some predefined list of values (R5). Are these R1-R5 correct and at least partially reflect what you expect from the Perl script?

Comment: Now, let's move on to the further requirements. R6: all lines in the output should be ordered by the third field based on a predefined list of values. I suppose the actual list will contain all possible values for the third field. Is this correct?

Comment: R7: we should filter the input and only process lines starting with "ATOM" as the initial script suggests? Is this correct?

Comment: sorry for the trouble, but I want to sort ATOM and HETATM both separate, There is only one problem I am getting in ATOM sort is: not able to sort predefined list of values.(It should be random atom name in input file, may be first is 4 row and second is 1 row). same I want to sort HETATM also, in HETATM getting problem: some of input file is like that: HETATM15056 O4B NAD A 500 14.003 14.203 8.927 1.00 17.39 O, so our program is discarding.

Comment: In this case, I'd suggest to perprocess input and propare two hashes - one for ATOM and the other for HETATM line. The hash keys would be possible atom names (CE1, CG, etc.) and the values being arrays of lines corresponding to that names. This will help us to output the lines in the order based on some name sequence. The input line parsing should also be revised towards positional approach since the field don't seem to be space delimited now.

Comment: As this getting too diverse for the original question I suggest to continue discussion by e-mail. Please find one on my profile page and drop a message referring this SO question and I'll answer with an updated script.

Comment: I mailed you script, can you check your e-mail?

Comment: can you please let me know the solution? I hove to analysis my data, please its urgent for me, sorry for  the trouble